# Autofac 6 - register a decorator as also implementing another interface

Tags: c#, decorator, autofac

before Autofac 6, I could do something like:

```
builder.RegisterType<ResourceStorageParallelOperationsLimitDecorator>()
       .As(new DecoratorService(typeof(IResourceStorage)))
       .As<INetworkQueueMetrics>();
```

In short, I could tell Autofac that all `IResourceStorage` instances should be decorated by `ResourceStorageParallelOperationsLimitDecorator` and that this decorator also offered the service `INetworkQueueMetrics`.

Now, in v6, if I do:

```
builder.RegisterDecorator<ResourceStorageParallelOperationsLimitDecorator,
                          IResourceStorage>()
```

I cannot continue the call with `.As<>(...)`.

And if I try to amend the registration of `ResourceStorageParallelOperationsLimitDecorator` like:

```
builder.RegisterDecorator<ResourceStorageParallelOperationsLimitDecorator,
                          IResourceStorage>();
builder.RegisterType<ResourceStorageParallelOperationsLimitDecorator>()
       .As<INetworkQueueMetrics>()
       .SingleInstance();
```

then this leads to `INetworkQueueMetrics` and `IResourceStorage` being resolved as two different instances of `ResourceStorageParallelOperationsLimitDecorator`, see the following test:

```
[Test]
public void INetworkQueueMetrics_resolves_to_the_same_instance_as_ResourceStorage()
{
  var container = BuildContainer();
  var resourceStorage = container.Resolve<IResourceStorage>();
  var networkMetrics = container.Resolve<INetworkQueueMetrics>();

  resourceStorage.Should().BeSameAs(networkMetrics); // <<<< FAILS
}
```

There are plenty of overrides for `ContainerBuilder.RegisterDecorator()`, maybe one of them would let me do what I need, but frankly their usage is not all that clear to me.

Any idea how I can get the semantics I want with Autofac v6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing is an intentional behavior. The point of a decorator is to *decorate* - it's basically a "value-add proxy." A decorator, in and of itself, doesn't expose a whole separate service - its sole purpose is to wrap something else. It only worked before somewhat accidentally - via a leaky abstraction in the way the fluent registration syntax functioned. That leak got "plugged" with the latest version.

If you need something to wrap a component *and change the services exposed*, **that's an adapter** and [Autofac does have adapter support, too](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html).

And, of course, if you need something more general purpose (like "log every call made to this thing"), [you can use type interceptors](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html).

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there is a use case to have both.  See contrived example below:

```cs
public interface IService
{
    void SetValue(MyType value);
}

public interface ICachedService: IService
{
    MyType CachedValue { get; }
}
```

And here's how I have it registered:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<Service, IService>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterDecorator<CachedService, IService>();
builder.Register<ICachedService>(ctx =>(ICachedService)ctx.Resolve<IService>());
```